# how to the generate the same string from two other two string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to generate the same string from two other string.

For example,  have string1 = "abcdef" and string2 = "ghijklmnop", I want to combine these two string in a way that I can have the same combination result even if the order of the two string is different.

to make clearer: lets suppose I am using the + operator to generate that string, so there would be two results : result = string1+string2 or result = string2+string1, which are totally different.

is there a javascript function that can generate a string from two string passed in parameters, even the order of the string passed in parameters is  different? if not how can I do it myself ?

Comment: your question is unclear - please show the expected "result"

Comment: Uncleare what you are asking, where does the order come from and what is the expected result?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it is clear now

Comment: No, it's still totally unclear, since you haven't described what determines which string comes first.   What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: the problem has been solved by @zhenguoli, for the order of the strings they are randomly ordered. the problem is that I want to have the same concatenation result even if the order of the string changes. you can have a look at the accepted answer as it may be more clear than my question.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can manually check the alphabetic order of the string argument like the following function:

```
function mergestr(str1, str2) {
    if (str1 > str2)
        return str2 + str1;
    else
        return str1 + str2;
}

var str1 = 'abcd'
var str2 = 'ghij'

mergestr(str1, str2)
>"abcdghij"
mergestr(str2, str1)
>"abcdghij"
```